# Error trying to freeze file using pyttsx3 - module sapi5 not found

Tags: python, text-to-speech, cx-freeze

I have made a program using pyttsx3 and voice recognition - it works fine on my IDLE python editor when I run it, but I recently tried to freeze it to an .exe file (So my friends could see it) and it came up with an error saying

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5`

I have no idea what this is about - I assume it doesn't automatically get that file when building?

Here is my setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32' : base = 'Win32GUI'

opts = { 'include_files' : ['splash.py', 'ohelp.py', 'oink.gif'] , 'includes' : ['re'], 'packages': ['pyttsx3.drivers',
'pyttsx3.drivers.dummy',
'pyttsx3.drivers.espeak',
'pyttsx3.drivers.nsss',
'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5']}

setup(name = "OinK", version = "1.0", description = "A voice assistant", author = "**********", options = {"build.exe" : opts}, executables = [ Executable("voice.py", base = base)])
```

Then ran it in CMD with

`python setup.py build`

And everything worked fine except the pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5 not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it - some of the compiled files were in a different directory (with the module files)

Not sure why but I copied them int othe right place and it works